# What do you think the best strategy would by to creating a temp XML file, sending it with FTP and then getting rid of it in a web app?

Tags: java, spring, ftp

I am creating a web application using Spring. One requirement is after processing a client request to create a XML document then send the XML via FTP to a FTP server and then get rid of the file.
What do you think the best strategy would by to creating a temp XML file, sending it with FTP and then getting rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a temp file at all. If your xml files are not big, you can use DOM to create the document in memory, and then write it directly to the FTP stream. Use Apache commons-net for easier ftp upload.

Comment: I am guessing you are suggesting to write my XML to a ByteInputStream and after finishing with FTP to get rid of it.

Comment: the commons-net gives  you this option